# Copy a range and not the entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for matching values in column 'B' with the value in Cell 'M15' and copy and delete those rows.

I only need to copy and delete a range (A to J) and not the entire row.

```
Sub MoveRows()

Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, Sht3 As Worksheet
Dim tfRow As Range, C As Range 
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Sht3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
With Sht1
   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 

   Set tfRow = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)

For Each C In tfRow

    If IsEmpty(C) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If C.Value = .Range("M15").Value Then 
        If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
            Set CopyRng = Application.Union(CopyRng, C)   
        Else
            Set CopyRng = C
        End If
    End If

Next C
End With

If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then

   LastRow = Sht3.Cells(Sht3.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   CopyRng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sht3.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
   CopyRng.EntireRow.Delete (xlShiftUp)

End If
```

Comment: You do under stand your data will shift when you delete. Or do you just want to clear the cells?

Comment: Does `CopyRng.Delete (xlShiftUp)` not do what you want to do?

Comment: @GMalc I want to copy the data into Sheet 3 and then delete it from Sheet 1. I do want it to shift. Only problem is not the entire row, only A to J.

Comment: @JoshEller I don't want to copy and delete the entire row, only the range from A to J.

Comment: Ok... so why are you running `CopyRng.EntireRow.Copy` and `CopyRng.EntireRow.Delete`?? Just get rid of the `.EntireRow`

Comment: @JoshEller Thank you! For .Copy as well? How do i specify that I only want to copy range from A to J?

Comment: Is `CopyRng` not the range you want to copy? If it's just a cell on the row, then use `CopyRng.EntireRow.Range("A1:J1")` for both the `.copy` and `.delete`.

Comment: @JoshEller I used EntireRow.Range("A1:J1") but it copies only the first row, and not all the matching rows of CopyRng.

Answer (score 0):

The basic code below uses an auto-filter(much faster then looping) and copies the visible cells in the range to the first empty cell in column A.

Deleting part of your data will cause the rows to shift and possible screw up your data. I also provided a line of code to only clear you range.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, lRow As Long, Rng As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
lRow = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ws1.Range("M15").Value

    ws1.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rng.Rows.Count, 10)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=ws3.Range("A" & lRow + 1)

    'You must clear the range and then remove the filter before deleting blank cells.
    ws1.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rng.Rows.Count, 10)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
    ws1.Cells.AutoFilter
    ws1.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rng.Rows.Count, 10)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Hello @GMalc The code works. However, it replaces the data in Sheet 3 (not copying from the LastRow + 1). Also, it deletes the entire row from Sheet 1 and not the range A to J.

Comment: I could get the copying to work. But it's deleting entire rows. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Siddharth try my edited code, i think the Rng was causing problems with selecting the range to copy.

Comment: Hello, it is still deleting the entire sheet row.

Comment: @Siddharth Try my edit, Excel has issues when trying to delete a range of cells in a filtered range, it just deletes the rows. The workaround is to clear the visible cells in a filtered range, then remove the filter and delete the blank cells in the range.